# Distorting a range of pixels to make parts of an image appear to "jiggle"

Tags: java, image-processing, image-manipulation

I'm working on making part of an image visually seem to "jiggle".

If you can imagine shaking a plate of jello, the fluid motion in which it moves back and fourth (three dimensionally) is what I'd like to achieve.

Here's an example: http://www.jigglystuff.com/

Here's a gif demonstrating the desired movement: [image]

I was thinking that a few things I'll have to do are:

When the part of the image is dragged by the cursor and ...

- moves to the right, the pixels to the right of the cursor will condense/overlap and the pixels on the left will expand, appearing to *bend* to the right
- moves to the left, the pixels to the left of the cursor of movement will condense/overlap and the pixels on the right will expand, appearing to *bend* to the left
- same logic for vertical directions

I'm not sure how to go about this -- any examples, expansion to my logic, or resources would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe, you can try [WarpFilter](http://www.jhlabs.com/ip/filters/WarpFilter.html) or [FieldWarpFilter](http://www.jhlabs.com/ip/filters/FieldWarpFilter.html) in `Filter.jar` from JH Labs?

Comment: Looks like a good start!

Comment: How can i get access to downloading `filter.jar`

Comment: Huh, it's there...just a matter of reading the `Filters` section page [download](http://www.jhlabs.com/ip/filters/download.html)

Comment: Thanks, couldn't find the download section

Comment: Does anyone has an example of FieldWarpFilter usage? It seems I can not apply this filter on an image.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve the "scaling" that creates the jiggle effect in your example, use a control texture and a suitable mapping function (eg. exponential relative to an anchor point you've defined). To isolate the parts you want to make jiggle, use a regular multiply masking step.

There's an example of displacement using a control texture [here](http://vvvv.org/contribution/displacement-map). Combine this with your own scaling filter, or one of those linked in the comments, and you should be good to go!

So, to reiterate:

1. Create a control texture based on your mouse position
2. Mask your image
3. Apply the vector field algorithm of your choice and design

Comment: A texture that is used like a parameter. That is, you sample the control texture to get per-pixel parameter values. In this case, the control texture for the displacement map contains direction vectors in the RGB channels, and an intensity value in the alpha channel.